# Contacts list in account object

Tags: apex, soql, account, contact

I tried to use contacts list inside account object like this :

```
Account a = new Account();
Contact c = new Contact();

c.lastName ='Test';

a.name ='Test';
a.contacts.add(c);
insert a;
```

The account has been inserted successfully , but the contact doesn't why and how i can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first insert account and use the accound id to insert contact so that contact gets linked to the account. Example below

```
Account a = new Account(); 
a.name ='Test';
insert a;

Contact c = new Contact();
c.lastName ='Test';
c.AccountId = a.Id;
insert c;
```

From [Salesforce documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_dml_examples_insert_update.htm), check the section **Inserting Related Records**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a DML to insert the contact. You are only inserting "a" , which it is the account. 
You need to insert "c" as well. Add insert c;